# Not able to transfer a file through SCP to my aws ec2 ( connection time out /lost connection

Tags: ssh, putty, amazon-web-services, scp

It's as simple as I described on the title. I want to upload a .gz file into the ec2 but I get

```
"connect to host ----- port 22: Connection timed out / connection lost"
```

I'm really new to this thing so I don't know what information you guys might need for this, but I'm using a ubuntu, the key I'm using seems to work fine for everything else.

Something else that might be helpful on understanding this is that I managed to do it before in another ec2 instance with almost the same configuration, but using a .tar file instead of a .gz

Please help, sorry for the lack of information, I will provide if asked as fast as possible.

**EDIT**

Ok, so here it is the command I was using:

```
scp -i "dumbkey.pem" dumbbot.tar.gz \ubuntu@ec2-18-222-123-36.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/tmp
```

The key and the file are located in the same folder, the key being the file "dumbkey.pem".

One other thing I forgot to mention and that is very important is that the .gz file is a docker image that I'm trying to upload on my instance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you're running ssh/scp, ie. what command you're using. Include anything relevant from your .ssh/config file. And indicate what key it's supposed to use to authenticate to this server.

Comment: There you go. Anything else could help you ?

Comment: After investigating for a while, I realized that port 22 is not open. I tried a online test and it did not respond as well, so maybe the problem is not on my instance, which is kind of weird since I can connect putty with it, which would require a response in that port, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Aparently, the problem was on my key permisions, if you chmod to change your key permissions then you should be able to copy things through scp again.